# How to cut data in such way?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a such dataset which y data is shown on the histogram below. I want to cut it so the biggest value in vertical axis will be lets say 2000. Each y corresponds to X case in another numpy array. How can I reduce this dataset?

```py
idx_acc = np.where((y > 0) & (y < 200))[0]
plt.hist(y[idx_acc], bins=int(y[idx_acc].max()));
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Here's my y file:
[y_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/194ySs1ZVDfvlzfC2AZMz7uB6qJIqiPgH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you also share `y` ?

Comment: ```y``` is only an array created from list. 1D array that contains values from range (0, 200), that's all. Nothing special.

Comment: Can you still post `y` here? `y = np.arange(200)` does not reproduce your figure. Is your goal to scale `y`, such that the maximum y-value in the histogram is e.g. `2000` or did I miss the point? To me, the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @André Done. Check the post once more. :)

Comment: Your `y` data file does not correspond to the figure shown.

Comment: @D4w1d You haven't posted it, you've linked it. What happens when you stop making the file on Drive public? Or delete it to save space? Or delete your account? The link will effectively be useless to all future readers and they'll lose important information that might've helped them relate their problem to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually calculate the histogram, filter, then create a bar plot:

```
# Get the count and edges of the histogram
counts, edges = np.histogram(y[idx_acc], bins=int(y[idx_acc].max()))

# Select only counts below 4000
sel = counts <= 4000

# Calculate the centers of the bars, and their widths
# (The number of edges is one more than the number of counts)
left = edges[:-1][sel]
right = edges[1:][sel]
center = (left + right)/2
width = right - left

# Create the bar plot
plt.bar(center, counts[sel], width=width)
plt.show()
```

[image: Filtered histogram]

(Note that the figure/data is different compared to that in the question, because the supplied example y-data doesn't match the figure in the question.)

---

If your intention is to show also the large bins, just clipped to a maximum value, it's actually a bit easier:

```
counts, edges = np.histogram(y[idx_acc], bins=int(y[idx_acc].max()))
counts = np.clip(counts, 0, 4000)
# There is no selection for the centers and widths: include all 
plt.bar((edges[:-1] + edges[1:])/2, counts2, width=(edges[1:] - edges[:-1]))
plt.show()
```

[image: Clipped histogram]